# Javascript async array manipulation blocks UI

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, vue.js, promise

my problem is quite easy to explain, but even though I've looked over the internet, the solution it's not really working, and I might be missing something.
The problem is: I have a huge array (let's say around 1000 elements) which is coming from an API Call. I know, I shouldn't even have 1thousand elements, but this is about understanding the concept behind this issue.

Now, I need to do some manipulation with this array, and actually iterate through some fields of the same element as well!

When I do this, my all UI (built in VueJs) blocks. I can't do anything for a couple of seconds (the time the iteration ends).

I've tried with something like this

```
let storedValues = []
setTimeout(async () => {
  let asyncList = list.map(async row => {
    let numbers = []
    let asyncNumbers = row.numbers.map(async number => {
      numbers.push(number)
    })
    await Promise.all(asyncNumbers)
    storedValues.push(numbers)
  })
  await Promise.all(asyncList)
}, 0);
```

the structure i'm trying to iterate is like this:

```
list = [
  {
    id: 1,
    numbers: [1,2,3,4,5,6]
  },
    {
    id: 2,
    numbers: [10,44,33,1,4,6]
  },
    {
    id: 3,
    numbers: [1,2,3,4,5,6]
  }
]
```

I actually tried with and without settimeout, since as far as I understood everything which is in a settimeout, is executed outside the main event-loop.

I even tried webworkes with a postmessage, but it actually doesn't solve the problem

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Edit: I edited the structure and the code since I've been asked for better understanding.

The purpose is

Thanks.

Comment: The code as posted has syntax errors, and it's not clear exactly what it should look like.

Comment: you tried to do the process in workers but it was still sync ??

Comment: Also there's no point passing an `async` function to `setTimeout()`; it won't pay attention to the returned promise.

Comment: @Pointy Basically the code does nothing, this small sample just iterates without purpose for the sake of let you see what I was trying.. but I would like to understand the main issue.

Comment: @h1b9b Yes i tried, but maybe i did something wrong with that

Comment: Well without seeing the *actual* code, and without seeing the *actual* data structure, it's impossible to say. You say there are 1000 items, but the code you posted suggest that it's at least a 2-dimensional data structure with each item having its own list of values (`iterableField`). How big are those?  Performing an operation 1000 times some large number can take a long time.

Comment: Just a note, code inside a setTimeout is actually being executed on a the main event loop, just not right now. The only way to do work on a different thread is using web workers.

Comment: The question marked as duplicate might be the answer. Thanks.